# Bash command with cut and pipe, No such file or directory error

Tags: bash, pipe, cut, tr

I am on Windows and I use cmdr shell. This command doesn't work :

```
 cut -s -d'"' -f2 file.txt | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]
```

I get this error :

> ```
>  cut: '|': No such file or directory
>  cut: tr: No such file or directory
>  cut: '[A-Z]': No such file or directory
>  cut: '[a-z]': No such file or directory
> ```

Moreover, the command works well and gives some results:

```
 cut -s -d'"' -f2 file.txt
```

The following command also works well:

```
 tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" < file.txt
```

Comment: For those wondering like I did, it's [this emulator](http://cmder.net/).

Comment: Also, is the missing trailing `"` a copy-paste error? It looks like it could be the reason of your problem if this shell has weird parsing rules. Otherwise it could be weird characters ; I suggest retrying to write the command by hand (rather than relying on copy-paste, especially from MS Office source and their diabolical auto-correct)

Comment: Also porting command from Windows to Unix (or viceversa) could be afflicted from the Format (e.g. Dos\Windows -> Unix)

Comment: That's why, I wanted to use cmdr, the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Cut's man page says:

```
cut OPTION... [FILE]...
       Print selected parts of lines from each FILE to standard output.
```

The error you received is informing the user that cmdr passed all the arguments to cut as additional files. Cut then tried to open those files (e.g '|') and failed to find a file by that name.

```
cut: '|': No such file or directory
cut: tr: No such file or directory
cut: '[A-Z]': No such file or directory
cut: '[a-z]': No such file or directory
```